# Is this a correct contract code with fixed supply?

Tags: contract-invocation

Can anybody tell me what is the function of constant private unite256?is there an option to increase the supply in this contract?

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.17;

library SafeMathMod {// Partial SafeMath Library

    function sub(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256 c) {
        require((c = a - b) < a);
    }

    function add(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256 c) {
        require((c = a + b) > a);
    }
}

contract ETHDEX {//is inherently ERC20
    using SafeMathMod for uint256;

    /**
    * @constant name The name of the token
    * @constant symbol  The symbol used to display the currency
    * @constant decimals  The number of decimals used to dispay a balance
    * @constant totalSupply The total number of tokens times 10^ of the number of decimals
    * @constant MAX_UINT256 Magic number for unlimited allowance
    * @storage balanceOf Holds the balances of all token holders
    * @storage allowed Holds the allowable balance to be transferable by another address.
    */

    string constant public name = "ETHDEX";

    string constant public symbol = "EDEX";

    uint8 constant public decimals = 8;

    uint256 constant public totalSupply = 21000000e8;

    uint256 constant private MAX_UINT256 = 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF;

    mapping (address => uint256) public balanceOf;

    mapping (address => mapping (address => uint256)) public allowed;

    event Transfer(address indexed _from, address indexed _to, uint256 _value);

    event TransferFrom(address indexed _spender, address indexed _from, address indexed _to, uint256 _value);

    event Approval(address indexed _owner, address indexed _spender, uint256 _value);

    function ETHDEX() public {balanceOf[msg.sender] = totalSupply;}

    /**
    * @notice send `_value` token to `_to` from `msg.sender`
    *
    * @param _to The address of the recipient
    * @param _value The amount of token to be transferred
    * @return Whether the transfer was successful or not
    */
    function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value) public returns (bool success) {
        /* Ensures that tokens are not sent to address "0x0" */
        require(_to != address(0));
        /* Prevents sending tokens directly to contracts. */
        require(isNotContract(_to));

        /* SafeMathMOd.sub will throw if there is not enough balance and if the transfer value is 0. */
        balanceOf[msg.sender] = balanceOf[msg.sender].sub(_value);
        balanceOf[_to] = balanceOf[_to].add(_value);
        Transfer(msg.sender, _to, _value);
        return true;
    }

    /**
    * @notice send `_value` token to `_to` from `_from` on the condition it is approved by `_from`
    *
    * @param _from The address of the sender
    * @param _to The address of the recipient
    * @param _value The amount of token to be transferred
    * @return Whether the transfer was successful or not
    */
    function transferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint256 _value) public returns (bool success) {
        /* Ensures that tokens are not sent to address "0x0" */
        require(_to != address(0));
        /* Ensures tokens are not sent to this contract */
        require(_to != address(this));

        uint256 allowance = allowed[_from][msg.sender];
        /* Ensures sender has enough available allowance OR sender is balance holder allowing single transsaction send to contracts*/
        require(_value <= allowance || _from == msg.sender);

        /* Use SafeMathMod to add and subtract from the _to and _from addresses respectively. Prevents under/overflow and 0 transfers */
        balanceOf[_to] = balanceOf[_to].add(_value);
        balanceOf[_from] = balanceOf[_from].sub(_value);

        /* Only reduce allowance if not MAX_UINT256 in order to save gas on unlimited allowance */
        /* Balance holder does not need allowance to send from self. */
        if (allowed[_from][msg.sender] != MAX_UINT256 && _from != msg.sender) {
            allowed[_from][msg.sender] = allowed[_from][msg.sender].sub(_value);
        }
        Transfer(_from, _to, _value);
        return true;
    }

    /**
    * @dev Transfer the specified amounts of tokens to the specified addresses.
    * @dev Be aware that there is no check for duplicate recipients.
    *
    * @param _toAddresses Receiver addresses.
    * @param _amounts Amounts of tokens that will be transferred.
    */
    function multiPartyTransfer(address[] _toAddresses, uint256[] _amounts) public {
        /* Ensures _toAddresses array is less than or equal to 255 */
        require(_toAddresses.length <= 255);
        /* Ensures _toAddress and _amounts have the same number of entries. */
        require(_toAddresses.length == _amounts.length);

        for (uint8 i = 0; i < _toAddresses.length; i++) {
            transfer(_toAddresses[i], _amounts[i]);
        }
    }

    /**
    * @dev Transfer the specified amounts of tokens to the specified addresses from authorized balance of sender.
    * @dev Be aware that there is no check for duplicate recipients.
    *
    * @param _from The address of the sender
    * @param _toAddresses The addresses of the recipients (MAX 255)
    * @param _amounts The amounts of tokens to be transferred
    */
    function multiPartyTransferFrom(address _from, address[] _toAddresses, uint256[] _amounts) public {
        /* Ensures _toAddresses array is less than or equal to 255 */
        require(_toAddresses.length <= 255);
        /* Ensures _toAddress and _amounts have the same number of entries. */
        require(_toAddresses.length == _amounts.length);

        for (uint8 i = 0; i < _toAddresses.length; i++) {
            transferFrom(_from, _toAddresses[i], _amounts[i]);
        }
    }

    /**
    * @notice `msg.sender` approves `_spender` to spend `_value` tokens
    *
    * @param _spender The address of the account able to transfer the tokens
    * @param _value The amount of tokens to be approved for transfer
    * @return Whether the approval was successful or not
    */
    function approve(address _spender, uint256 _value) public returns (bool success) {
        /* Ensures address "0x0" is not assigned allowance. */
        require(_spender != address(0));

        allowed[msg.sender][_spender] = _value;
        Approval(msg.sender, _spender, _value);
        return true;
    }

    /**
    * @param _owner The address of the account owning tokens
    * @param _spender The address of the account able to transfer the tokens
    * @return Amount of remaining tokens allowed to spent
    */
    function allowance(address _owner, address _spender) public view returns (uint256 remaining) {
        remaining = allowed[_owner][_spender];
    }

    function isNotContract(address _addr) private view returns (bool) {
        uint length;
        assembly {
        /* retrieve the size of the code on target address, this needs assembly */
        length := extcodesize(_addr)
        }
        return (length == 0);
    }

    // revert on eth transfers to this contract
    function() public payable {revert();}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> is there an option to increase the supply in this contract

No. Since your total supply is marked constant, it can not be increased (or even decreased).

> what is the function of constant private unite256

- **Constant:** State variables can be declared as constant and the compiler does not reserve a storage slot for these variables and every occurrence is replaced by their constant value.
- **Private:**   Private functions and state variables are only visible for the contract they are defined in and not in derived contracts.
- **int / uint**: Signed and unsigned integers of various sizes. Keywords
  uint8 to uint256 in steps of 8 (unsigned of 8 up to 256 bits) and
  int8 to int256. uint and int are aliases for uint256 and int256,
  respectively.

**Note:** Everything that is inside a contract is visible to all external observers. Making something private only prevents other contracts from accessing and modifying the information, but it will still be visible to the whole world outside of the blockchain.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer to your question but I noticed something that could be improved. In your transferFrom function, there is no need for creating a variable called allowance and assigning it the total amount of tokens the spender is allowed to spend. You could just simply write, 
`require(_value <= allowed[_from][msg.sender])`. This would use less gas too.

Comment: uint256 constant private MAX_UINT256 = 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF;
what this function is for? Can you please read this contract code and confirm that the token supply will not be increase in the future